Как в n2o сделать шаблон по маске переменной длинны?
<field-lock src="FieldLock" lockFieldName="lock.birthCertificate" showLock="{showLock}">
                    <masked-input mask="999999" id="birthNumberRf" label="Номер">
                        <dependencies>
                            <set-value on="bornInRf,stillborn">
                                if (!bornInRf || stillborn) return null;
                            </set-value>
                            <visibility on="bornInRf,stillborn">bornInRf &amp;&amp; !stillborn</visibility>
                            <requiring on="bornInRf,stillborn">bornInRf &amp;&amp; !stillborn</requiring>
                        </dependencies>
                    </masked-input>
</field-lock>

аттрибут  mask="999999" отвечает за то, чтобы аттрибут содержал 6 цифр. Как сделать так, чтобы он был переменной длинны, 6 или 7 цифр?

Похоже, вам надо спрашиватть разработчиков этого фреймворка N2O, где фронтенд написан на ReactJS.
